# Is anyone familiar with number selection by a vertical circular scrollable list by edge fading for a circular illusion, like a suite case number lock

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, carousel

I need a number selection list which should spin or rotate vertically like a suite case number lock system which the user should able to scroll up and down and the list should slide circularly like a suite case number locking system.

There should be 6 numbers arranged vertically and each digit contains 0-9 digits which should slide upward and downward. The top most and bottom most element of vertical spin should fade while scrolling which gives user an illusion like circular sliding like a suite case number lock rotating.

Actually I am working with a ticket selection process for an application.

Please check the requirement image which I provided with this description

[This is the Requirement Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk0EB.png)

Comment: have you try this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String passCode = "123456";
  List<int> intList = <int>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                            itemExtent: 100,
                            perspective: 0.01,
                            overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.32,
                            onSelectedItemChanged: (int value) {
                              intList[i] = value;
                            },
                            childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Text(i.toString())
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  String strFinalResult = "";
                  final String strResult1 = intList[0].toString();
                  final String strResult2 = intList[1].toString();
                  final String strResult3 = intList[2].toString();
                  final String strResult4 = intList[3].toString();
                  final String strResult5 = intList[4].toString();
                  final String strResult6 = intList[5].toString();
                  strFinalResult = strResult1 +
                      strResult2 +
                      strResult3 +
                      strResult4 +
                      strResult5 +
                      strResult6;
                  print("Result1: $strResult1");
                  print("Result2: $strResult2");
                  print("Result3: $strResult3");
                  print("Result4: $strResult4");
                  print("Result5: $strResult5");
                  print("Result6: $strResult6");
                  print(strFinalResult == passCode ? "Pass" : "Fail");
                },
                child: const Text("Check"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```